# Arrange tags by width to fit container

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styled-components

I have made tags component which each tag has a different width.

The container is fixed with max-width which forces the tags to be in the right order to fits in the max-width, here's an example of the issue.

https://codesandbox.io/s/sort-tags-ust5m?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Wanted to know if u have any idea how can i re-order the tags to fit in the efficient layout in the container?

Thank you,

Comment: Do you want something like this? https://nimb.ws/gLYbtX

Answer (score 0):

You should look into a packing rectangles into rectangles problem. Here is a small [article with a code example](https://observablehq.com/@mourner/simple-rectangle-packing).
Each time the size of the tag container changes (resize event fires) you should re-render the list of tags sorted by the script in the example above. Of cause the script should be adapted to your particular case first.